# Incomplete response received from application digital ocean Rails deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, digital-ocean

I have deployed a Rails app to digital Ocean on Ubuntu 16 with Capistrano, Nginx and Phusion Passenger and I am getting the following error from:

```
sudo tail /var/log/nginx/error.log

App 4752 stderr:  from /home/deploy/maverick/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/application.rb:246:in `env_config'
App 4752 stderr:  from /home/deploy/maverick/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:693:in `build_request'
App 4752 stderr:  from /home/deploy/maverick/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/application.rb:521:in `build_request'
App 4752 stderr:  from /home/deploy/maverick/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:521:in `call'
App 4752 stderr:  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
App 4752 stderr:  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:152:in`accept_and_process_next_request'
App 4752 stderr:  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:113:in `main_loop'
App 4752 stderr:  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:416:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
App 4752 stderr:  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'

[ W 2017-12-09 07:14:23.2585 25154/T4 age/Cor/Con/InternalUtils.cpp:96 ]: 
[Client 1-5] Sending 502 response: application did not send a complete response
```

Comment: We probably need an longer stack trace.  Is there an error in your application?  You are looking for a file that is part of your rails app in the stack trace.